# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings

Tags: php

I realise that this question has been asked a number of times but I am yet to find a solution to this problem.

I am using pChart (pData v2.1.4). It works fine on the hosting site which is running php v5.6.30 but I getting a fatal error with the same code on XAMMP which is running php v7.2.5.

The error refers to this line in pData: (NOTE: pData is a class written by a third party and so not my code)

```
function convertToArray($Value)
    { $Values = ""; $Values[] = $Value; return($Values); }
```

Any suggestions as to how to resolve the problem? I have tried declaring **$Values** as an array earlier in the code but this seemed to cause more errors.

Also, is this php version related and an error that I am going to start getting if my hosting site moves on to a newer version php?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `$Values` as string:

```
$Values = "";
```

Fix replacing with array:

```
function convertToArray($Value)
{
    $Values = [];
    $Values[] = $Value;
    return $Values;
}
```

But, in my opinion, there is no reason to use this function.
In your code, just define an array of the same variable with:

```
$Value = [$Value];
```

It will do the same as your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert string to array (`$Values = ""; $Values[] = $Value;`), so right variant:

```
function convertToArray($value) {
    return [$value];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Values should declared as Array Try this.

```
function convertToArray($Value){
 $Values = [];
 $Values[] = $Value;
 return $Values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function convertToArray($Value){
   $Values = array(); // initialize 

   if ( isset($Value) ) $Values[] = $Value; 

   return($Values); 
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.